# java : hide or display table according to condition

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a form with some inputs; each input returns a list of data which is displayed in a table in another html page. Each input have a table to display it's data. My task is to do not display the data if the input is not entered by the user.

Here is my code

```
<!-- Country Table-->
                     <%for(int i = 0; i < countryList.length;i++){
                         if(countryList.length == 0)

                             break; 
                      %>
                     <div class="box" align="center">
                         <table  name="tab" align="center" class="gridtable">
                            <thead >
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width: 50%" scope="col">Entity Watch List Key</th>
                                    <th style="width: 50%" scope="col">Watch List Name</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                <tr>
                                <td style="width: 50%"><%out.println((String) (countryList[i].getEntityWatchListKey()));%></td>
                                <td style="width: 50%"><%out.println((String) (countryList[i].getEntityName()));%></td>
                                </tr>


                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </div>
                        <%}%>
```

I am using break to go out of the loop to do not display the table, is that true ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this condition before the for loop,

```
if(countryList.length != 0)
```

or

```
if(countryList.length > 0)
```

and then you need not use the break condition,

Furthermore the for loop you have currently defined will not work because if the length of the array is 0 then this condition i < countryList.length will become 0<0 and it will fail,so your for loop won't even be entered.So your current if condition `if(countryList.length == 0)` will not be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your code

```
<div class="box" align="center">
 <table  name="tab" align="center" class="gridtable">
    <thead >
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 50%" scope="col">Entity Watch List Key</th>
            <th style="width: 50%" scope="col">Watch List Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<%for(int i = 0; i < countryList.length;i++){ 
        if(countryList.length > 0) %>
            <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%"><%out.println((String) (countryList[i].getEntityWatchListKey()));%></td>
            <td style="width: 50%"><%out.println((String) (countryList[i].getEntityName()));%></td>
            </tr>

<%}%>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

For a good practice you have to repeat the row not the table.